# probability question on decision making

Tags: probability

A person is want to know whether stock A or stock B will perform
better next quarter. He seeks the opinions of two advisors. He knows
that each advisor will choose the better stock with probability $p$, independent
of the other. His strategy is as follows: if the two advisors agree, buy
the stock on which they agree. If they disagree, toss a fair coin to
decide which stock to buy. Evaluate his strategy.

I think when two advisor choose the same stock, the variance of that prob. $p$ will be lower, but what if they choose different stock? please give a direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\pi$: probabilty of selecting the winning stock. If $X$ is an indicator variable that takes $1$ if the better stock was selected, then $\mathbf{E}X=\pi$. Now, this happens in two cases: if either both experts voted for it, or at least one. In the former case, the guy selects is w.p. $1$, in the latter w.p. $\frac{1}{2}$. Now use the formula of total probability to get $\pi$.